# Converting large dataframe into format supported by NetworkX

Tags: pyspark, networkx

I have a large dataframe which I would like to load and convert to a network using `NetworkX`

since the dataframe is large I cannot use `graph = nx.DiGraph(df.collect())` because `networkx` doesn't work with dataframes.

What is the most computationally efficient way of getting a dataframe (2 columns) into a format supported by NetworkX?

Comment: What do the columns represent, node ids? (ie. each row is an edge?)

Comment: yes!   thats correct

Comment: Roughly how large is the data? If you can output the dataframe to a simple file (like CSV), you may be able to use something like nx.read_adjlist() and pass in the file name.

Comment: it's around 50GB

Comment: @ChrisGS the data is stored in multiple files, is there a way I could loop through the files and read them in with nx.read_adjlist() or some other function that creates a dataformat supported by networkx ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PySpark, but one idea is to create the PySpark DataFrame (df) and a new NetworkXGraph (g). Then for each item in df.collect(), call (for example) g.add_edge(row[0], row[1]). This will automatically add the nodes to the graph as well. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to solve your problem though.

Comment: NetworkX can ingest several data formats (see the [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html)). Not sure how your files are formatted currently, but it might be easiest for you to use adjacency list format, which makes it easy to create a NetworkX graph.